# What's the easiest way to force n elements be showed in a row?

Tags: html, css

Here is a very detailed demo of what I want:

I want to keep the HTML as `group1` and use pure CSS to make it like `group2`.

I hope:

1. Only use CSS. The width of the button should be defined in the CSS;
2. The parent div of those buttons are not in a fixed width.
3. The `0` button should be in the middle (what I did is to put two buttons and hide them)
4. The button should be aligned one to one with the same margin between them. And the margin should be a dynamic value since the parent div is flexible.

I tried a lot of ways but failed to reach the perfect result. Is there anyone can drop any tips? Thanks!

```css
button{
width:27px;
height:27px;
margin:5px;
cursor:pointer;
}
.placeholder {opacity:0}
```

```html
<div class="group1">
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <button>4</button>
  <button>5</button>
  <button>6</button>
  <button>7</button>
  <button>8</button>
  <button>9</button>
  <button>0</button>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="group2">
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <br>
  <button>4</button>
  <button>5</button>
  <button>6</button>
  <br>
  <button>7</button>
  <button>8</button>
  <button>9</button>
  <br>
  <button class="placeholder">0</button>
  <button>0</button>
  <button class="placeholder">0</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is CSS grid:

```css
.group1 {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); /*Or simply : 1fr 1fr 1fr*/
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.group1 button:last-child {
  transform: translate(calc(100% + 10px));
}

button {
  width: 27px;
  height: 27px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="group1">
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <button>4</button>
  <button>5</button>
  <button>6</button>
  <button>7</button>
  <button>8</button>
  <button>9</button>
  <button>0</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @str and as you can see it's pretty well supported ;) unless you are using opera-mini

Comment: It does not work on Internet Explorer 11 (or any IE version). It does work in MS Edge.

Comment: @Sébastien honestly i don't care about IE :) but it can work with IE if we use the correct prefixes

Comment: @Sébastien he asked for an easy solution and I provided an easy one working with modern browsers, now people can still add more answers for old browsers if they want ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif A "good solution" always depends on the requirements. While compatibility with older browsers was not explicitly mentioned in the question, it is always good to mention it in the answer for future readers. I agree that CSS Grids *might* be a good solution, but you have to be aware of the implications.

Comment: @str am totally aware about implications ;) and I always mention browser support when it comes to new feature not already supported by modern browsers ... but when it's IE (the old non-supported dying browser) I don't pay attention as it's already known that all the new stuffs are not supported there. So I look into the future and not the past, as for me we should upgrade to supported browser and not stick to old non-supported one [my opinion].

Comment: @TemaniAfif It is not about you but about future readers. I added a compatibility note.

Comment: @TemaniAfif ...and you removed the compatibility note again. Very strange move.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it using flexbox, you can change the container's width and the items will adjust accordingly:

```css
button{
  width: 27px;
  height:27px;
  cursor:pointer;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

button:not(:nth-child(3n)) { 
  margin-right: calc((100% - 27px * 3) / 2);
}

button:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
 
.group1 {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: center; 
   width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="group1">
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <button>4</button>
  <button>5</button>
  <button>6</button>
  <button>7</button>
  <button>8</button>
  <button>9</button>
  <button>0</button>
</div>
```

Comment: you have fixed the width of the container what the OP doesn't want this Also you cannot control the margin easily like this, it's not fixed

Comment: If you remove the width the items will stretch accordingly which I guess the OP wants.
He said this in the question: "And the margin should be a dynamic value since the parent div is flexible."

Comment: Thanks. But why do you set the width of group1 to 33%? The width of group1 should be 100%. I hope the button will be stretched automatically. BTW, if I remove the width, it's not working properly.